# Laravel have same folder for multiple langs?

Tags: laravel

In laravel can I have default lang folder? In other words now I have

```
lang
   en
lang
   ru
```

I don't need to have each folder for each language because I read data from the database. I need something like this and it must work for all locales. Is it possible?

```
lang
  def
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In config/app.php:

```
   /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Application Fallback Locale
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | The fallback locale determines the locale to use when the current one
    | is not available. You may change the value to correspond to any of
    | the language folders that are provided through your application.
    |
    */

    'fallback_locale' => 'en',
```

The default fallback folder by default is lang/en. You can change it to **def**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have multiple languages in the same lang directory without additional configuration. Check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/localization) if you need additional guidance.

[image]